Automatically add private key identities to OpenSSH authentication agent ubuntu 24.04lts
On ubuntu gnome 24.04lts I have a yubikey and wanted to know instead of running the terminal command /usr/bin/ssh-add -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so each time I reboot the computer, is there a way for the computer to do this automatically when the yubikey is inserted or detected?
